# C# Printing out Arrays from a list

Tags: c#, arrays, list, search, printing

I am very new to coding and C#, and I need help with my program I am creating. 
This is a school assignment, and I just can't get it to work.

The program is simple, I have a Log book (List), and I should be able to create new logs (Each log have to be an individual Array) and save it to the List. I got that part worked out, but then I should be able to search for a specific log (Just by searching for the exact title, 00, of the log) and i should also be able to print every log(array) in the list out at once (0,00,01,02. 1,00,01,02 etc)

I have tried several things but I can't get it to work and it's hard to find solutions for my specific problem by only searching for it.

```
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //List & Array\\
        List<string[]> loggBok = new List<string[]> { }; 
        string[] newEntry = new string[3]; 

        //Variabler\\ - Variabler för sökord och Tid&Datum
        string searchTerm = "";
        DateTime time = DateTime.Now; 

        Console.WriteLine("\tVälkommen till Charlies loggbok.");


        //Bool & While loop\\
        bool isRunning = true;
        while (isRunning)

            try 
            {
                { //Loop start

                    //Meny\\
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\t[1] Skriv ett nytt inlägg i loggboken");
                    Console.WriteLine("\t[2] Sök efter inlägg i loggboken");
                    Console.WriteLine("\t[3] Skriv ut alla loggar i loggboken");
                    Console.WriteLine("\t[4] Rensa bort all text");
                    Console.WriteLine("\t[5] Avsluta programmet");

                    Console.Write("\n\tVälj siffra: ");

                    //Switch\\
                    int menyVal = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); 
                    switch (menyVal) 


                    {
                        case 1: 
                            Console.WriteLine("\nDu har valt att skriva in ett nytt inlägg.");
                            //string[] newEntry = new string[3];


                            //Nytt inlägg\\
                            Console.Write("Skriv in titeln: ");
                            newEntry[0] = Console.ReadLine(); 

                            Console.Write("Skriv in meddelandet: ");
                            newEntry[1] = Console.ReadLine();

                            time = DateTime.Now; 
                            var entryTime = Convert.ToString(time); 
                            newEntry[2] = entryTime;

                            loggBok.Add(newEntry); 

                            Console.WriteLine("\nInlägget är sparat i loggboken");
                            break;

                        case 2:
                            Console.WriteLine("\nVänligen skriv in titelt på inlägget för att söka fram det.");
                            Console.Write("\nSök efter: ");

                            searchTerm = Console.ReadLine(); 

                            var foundItem = false; 

                            foreach (var item in loggBok) 
                            {
                                if (item.Contains(searchTerm)) 
                                {
                                    foundItem = true;
                                    Console.WriteLine(item);
                                }
                            }



                            if (!foundItem) 
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Kunde inte hitta inlägget du sökt efter.");
                            }

                            break;

                        case 3:
                            foreach (var item in loggBok) 
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(item);
                            }
                            break;

                        case 4:
                            Console.Clear(); 
                            Console.WriteLine("\tFönstret är nu rensat.");
                            break;

                        case 5:
                            Console.WriteLine("\n\tHej då!");
                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); 
                            isRunning = false; //bool är falskt och stänger då av programmet (avslutar loopen)
                            break;


                        default: 
                            Console.Clear(); //Rensar konsolfönstret
                            Console.WriteLine("Felaktig inmatning, skriv en siffra från menyn");
                            break;

                    }
                } //Loop slut
            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nNågot gick fel!");
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
    }
}
}
```

This is the whole program so far, case 2 and 3 are the ones im having trouble with, the code currently inside those cases do not work.

case 2 is the search function. If i add more than 1 array, only the last one can be found, but the output shows "System.String[]" for each array added (if i add 2 arrays it shows the message 2 times)

and case 3 is the print-all function. It prints out all the arrays but the output is also only "System.String[]" for each array.

Thank you.

Comment: Just a small hint. Try to avoid using `var` at your stage of learning. It doesn't help you if you don't even have think about the types of your variables.

Comment: I know, I usually use the proper types for my variables but in this case I had to turn to var. I haven't really gone further in my learning than var, string and int, and my entryTime variable for example wouldn't accept string or int as the type

Comment: `var entryTime = Convert.ToString(time);` is very much a string variable. There's nothing to feel bad about, I am simply pointing out that using the explicit type is much more appropriate for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use nested loops like this.

```
foreach (var item in loggBok) 
{
   foreach (var s in item) 
      Console.WriteLine(s);
}
break;
```

Do the same for more scenaios. I did it for `case:3`. Hope it helps.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, basic, simple code fitting with the rest of the assignment's usage of code. Now the search and "write all" function is working perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you're not delving deep enough into the structure. Imagine it like so;

```
-List
   -Array(of type string)
      -string
      -string
      -string
```

So in your `foreach` loops, you're asking it to return the actual array object, which is why you're getting this result.

Just go one level deeper like so and then format the output as desired;

```
foreach (var item in loggBok)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0},{1},{2}", item[0], item[1], item[2]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider this fully fledged abomination of a code

for case 2:

```
            List<string[]> loggBok = new List<string[]>();
        string searchTerm = Console.ReadLine();

        bool foundItem = false;
        int index = 0;

        do
        {
            string[] log = loggBok[index];
            if(log[0] == searchTerm)
            {
                foundItem = true;
                Console.WriteLine("Found it.");
            }

        } while(foundItem == false && index > loggBok.Count);
```

See the usage of `do{}while();` , You have to loop atleast once, but only until you find the item or until you looped trhough the whole collection.

for case3:

```
for (int i = 0; i < loggBok.Count; i++)
        {
            string firstEntry = loggBok[i][0];
            string secondEntry = loggBok[i][1];
            string thirdEntry = loggBok[i][2];

            Console.WriteLine(firstEntry + " , " + secondEntry + " , " + thirdEntry);
        }
```

Here we use a for loop as we know exactly how many times we have to loop trough the your log.